# VBA Scraping: Object required

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

```
      Dim oIE As InternetExplorer
        Dim wwwAdd$, NazwaArk$, AdrStrony$
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument

        Dim wElement As HTMLAnchorElement
        Dim row As Long, col%, n%, pozDat% ' co to są te procenty??
        Dim PoprzedniElement As HTMLAnchorElement
        Dim Tekst As String
        Dim NrOferty As Variant
        Dim i, j As Integer
        Dim IleSekund As Integer
        Dim newHour As Variant
        Dim newMinute As Variant
        Dim newSecond As Variant
        Dim waitTime As Variant
        Dim link As Integer
        Dim maxlink As Integer  

Set oIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate AdrStrony, 2

row = row + 1

Do Until oIE.ReadyState = tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
Set doc = oIE.Document

      For Each wElement In doc.getElementsByClassName("info")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(3) ' "a" = a href
        MsgBox (wElement)
        Sheets("Oferty").Cells(1, 1).Value = wElement
        Next wElement
        oIE.Quit
```

MS VBA says that object is required, but when I delete (3) in the first line (actually 25th :)) "everything is allright". It gives me three MsgBoxes (1. Link that I want to take, 2. Empty, 3. Link that I want). So the easiest way is to take the 3rd option.

---

I implemented code by QHarr, but I wanted to take 20 links from one page of site (next step it will be doing on multiply pages), so I made a simple For Next:

```
Set oIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.Navigate AdrStrony, 2 'AdrStrony is the the www site address

For iNo = 0 To 20
 With oIE
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend 'I personally don't understand this line
        Set doc = oIE.document
        For Each wElement In doc.getElementsByClassName("info")(iNo).getElementsByTagName("a")
        'MsgBox (wElement)
            If iRow <> 2 Then 'Works like a charm, but how the magic works? What it does actually?
                iRow = iRow + 1
                On Error Resume Next '<=In case no href attribute
                Worksheets("Oferty").Cells(iRow, 1) = wElement.getAttribute("href")
                'Worksheets("Oferty").Cells(iRow, 1) = wElement.innerText
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            .Quit
        Next wElement

        'other code

    End With
Next iNo
```

But it shows Automation error (unknown error).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: There is no "3" in the first line : "Dim oIE As Internet Explorer"

Comment: @SolarMike I guess he means in this line `doc.getElementsByClassName("info")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(3)`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ that is not the first line... I did see that but it is about the 25th line... would be helpful to be pointed in the right direction...

Comment: @BartBart What does `MsgBox(doc.getElementsByClassName("info")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(3))` say?

Comment: shows three MsgBoxes (1. Link that I want to take, 2. Empty, 3. Link that I want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **New info:**

Based on your new info here is how you get the 20 listed properties on the first page without an open browser, using XHR:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument, i As Long
    Const BASE_URL As String = "http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/lista-ofert/?f_location_locality[0]=szczecin&submit=Szukaj&offset=0", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
        Dim propertyList As Object
        With html
            .body.innerHTML = sResponse
            Set propertyList = html.querySelectorAll(".info")
            For i = 0 To propertyList.Length - 1
                Debug.Print BASE_URL & Split(Split(propertyList.item(i).innerHTML, "about:/")(1), Chr$(34) & ">")(0)
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

You can get the number of pages of results (if you want to later loop them) with:

```
Dim numPages As Long
numPages = html.querySelectorAll(".pagination li")(6).innerText
```

It is not as robust as `.pagination li:nth-last-child(3)`, but it seems that VBA doesn't support that selector.

---

**Same thing with a browser:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SubCentalineAutomation()
    Dim myIE As InternetExplorer, propertyList As Object, i As Long
    Const BASE_URL As String = "http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl"
    Set myIE = New InternetExplorer

    With myIE
        .navigate "http://www.kontrakt.szczecin.pl/lista-ofert/?f_location_locality[0]=szczecin&submit=Szukaj&offset=0"
        .Visible = True
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set propertyList = .document.querySelectorAll("#properties header > a")
        For i = 0 To propertyList.Length - 1
                 Debug.Print BASE_URL & propertyList.item(i).getAttribute("href")
        Next i

        '.Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With

End Sub
```

---

### Old info (your original question):

**You want to get 2 out of 3 links in a collection**. This means that you don't want `doc.getElementsByClassName("info")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(3)` . The 3 indexes into the collection and returns a single element.
Showing relevant HTML, and the expected links, would have helped clarify matters here.

You don't show a definition for  `tagREADYSTATE`. I would go with  `While oIE.Busy Or oIE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend` to ensure page loaded.

In the `For Each` loop you show, if the selection is valid, an object would be returned as `wElement`. You then attempt `Sheets("Oferty").Cells(1, 1).Value = wElement`. I would expect, instead that you either use the .`innerText` property of `wElement`, or use `.getAttribute("href")`, to just have the link for the `a` tag.

Furthermore, I would use the Worksheets collection, and your incremented row variable within the loop and with an unambiguous name e.g. iRow.
To only get the 1st and 3rd links, you can then test the value of iRow to determine whether to retrieve the link e.g. `If iRow <> 2 Then`.

An example of what that might look like:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test1()
    'Other code
    Dim iRow
    With oIE
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set doc = oIE.document
        For Each wElement In doc.getElementsByClassName("info")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
            If iRow <> 2 Then
                iRow = iRow + 1
                On Error Resume Next '<=In case no href attribute
                Worksheets("Oferty").Cells(iRow, 1) = wElement.getAttribute("href")
                ' Worksheets("Oferty").Cells(iRow, 1) = wElement.innerText
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next wElement

        'other code
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for a help. It works partially. I still need some more explanation:

Comment: What would you like to know? :-)

Comment: I edited main post, and now it relates to yours. Also I added two more question in comments.

Comment: With an URL to test it is a little difficult to work out what is going on. You say you now want to 20 links? How does that relate to the original 2 out of 3? Please show some HTML from the page indicating the links you are after? It is also generally better etiquette to pose a new question, especially if peopl have answered your existing question, rather than change the question.

Comment: bit.ly/2Ls6NT7 - here is the link with the www. Okay, I'll remember.

Comment: These near the photos of the real estates. Mostly, they start with phrase: Szczecin.

Comment: I have updated the answer to pull all those (answers with and without open browser)

Comment: Wow man, that's cool. I need to figure it out. Hope you're open to some questions about it :)

Comment: Hey, I made it, thanks a LOT! Btw. Do you have some nice materials about VBA Scraping?

Comment: Sorry just seen this.... https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scrape-website-html.htm  and see the associated youtube videos.